# Blocking I/O vs NIO for connecting to four different devices in Android

Tags: java, android, nio

I am writing an Android application to simultaneously upgrade the firmware of four-five medical devices. Should i go with traditional blocking I/O employing thread per connection approach or non-blocking NIO approach.

The program is already working fine for upgarding one device at a time.

What would have greater overhead here ? java NIO overhead or context switching overhead

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Honestly, considering the possibly critical application of the devices you'll be upgrading, I'd stick with upgrading one device at a time and making sure there are no bugs there.

Comment: @Marcelo We have tested upgrading one device at a time and its working fine[with Blocking I/O]. Now we want to extend the same to simultaneous upgradation of multiple devices(say 4-5). For that we want to decide the best approach. Blocking I/O with thread per connection vs Non Blocking NIO with the complexity involved in it

Comment: At least from a project management stand, it would make sense to use the code you already have (and is tested) and just create some sort of `ExecutorService` running multiple threads of it. Then, if you *do* encounter performance issues, you do something about it...

Answer (score 2):

If the number of devices is four or five, and isn't going to grow by at least two orders of magnitude any time soon, I'd suggest you stick with blocking I/O and thread per connection model due to its simplicity and the fact that you are unlikely to see any performance improvements from NIO in this case and a performance drop is actually quite possible. Thread switching works quite well even for many more tasks than 4 or 5 and the programming model is so much simpler. If the communication code uses sockets, there may be an advantage in using NIO, though, because Selectors allow you to detect some kinds of broken connections better than IO Streams. Even for that case, however, I would recommend using NIO in a thread-per-client model, as it will probably save you lots of work on the code.

Comment: @Michel Thanks Michal for the input.

Comment: @Michel Thanks Michal for the input. I am seriously inclined to the Blocking I/O approach. I will present this before my team. What i am worried about is that for five connections, there will be a total of 10 threads(one for tx and other for rx for each device).

Comment: This depends on the kind of communication your code will perform. If it's some kind of query-response protocol, you can perform both reads and writes from a single thread. But even 10 threads per core is not very much (I'm talking about desktop or server-class machines, can't say for embedded devices). I assume your threads will spend most of their time waiting for I/O anyway, so there's no problem with having many more threads than CPUs in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> java NIO overhead or context switching overhead

That's the wrong question. NIO doesn't have much in the way of overhead, but you have to implement the 'context switching' yourself in your application, you can't just pretend it's gone away with NIO ... and your code that schedules between channels may not be as efficient as the operating system's thread scheduler. The real question is whether the saving in threads and more specifically thread stacks has any significance versus the greatly increased complexity of NIO code. Unless you are planning to service tens of thousand of connections it generally doesn't.

It's worth noting that the NIO model using selectors originated prior to threads, i.e. when the choice was between more complex code and more *processes.* These days there is a significant school of thought that holds that you should use blocking I/O and threads in almost all circumstances. There is a study and a paper out there somewhere, by I think Peter Lawrey, but I don't have the citation to hand.

Comment: an interesting and thoughtfull input.